# Why increment an indexed array behave as documented in numpy user documentation?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

**The example**

The documentation about [assigning value to indexed arrays](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) shows an example with unexpected results for those naive programmers.

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
>>> x
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] += 1
>>> x
array([ 0, 11, 20, 31, 40])
```

The documentation says people could naively expect the value of the array at `x[1]+1` being incremented three times, but instead it is assigned to `x[1]` three times.

**The Problem**

What really confuse me is that what i was expecting was the operation `x += 1` behave like it does in normal Python, as `x = x + 1`, so `x` resulting `array([11, 11, 31, 11])`. As in this example:

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
>>> x
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> x = x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] + 1
>>> x
array([11, 11, 31, 11])
```

**The Question**

First:

What is happening in the original example? can some one elaborate more the explanation?

Second:

It is a documented behavior, i'm Ok with that. But i think it should behave as i described because is what is expected from a Pythonistic point of view. So, just because i want to be convinced: is there a good reason it behave like it does over "my expected" behavior?

Comment: Dunno about the NumPy internals, but probably is has to do with that += is an inplace operation and + is not. I suspect that in the first case a view of the array is created (ignoring doubles) and than the += operation is applied. In the second case I suspect there is first made a copy of the view and than the + operation is made. (doesn't seem unreasonable to me (NumPy is sometimes less Pythonic and more C/Fortran-like (for good reasons)))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is the second example you give is not the same as the first. It's easier to understand if you look at the value of `x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] + 1` separately, which numpy calculates in both your examples.

The value of `x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] + 1` is what you had expected: `array([11, 11, 31, 11])`.

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
>>> x
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] + 1
array([11, 11, 31, 11])
```

In example 1, you assign this answer to elements 1 and 3 in the original array x. This means the new value 11 is assigned to element 1 three times.

However, in example 2, you replace the original array x with the new array `array([11, 11, 31, 11])`.

This is the correct equivalent code to your first example, and gives the same result.

```
>>> x = np.arange(0, 50, 10)
>>> x
array([ 0, 10, 20, 30, 40])
>>> x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] = x[np.array([1, 1, 3, 1])] + 1
>>> x
array([ 0, 11, 20, 31, 40])
```

Comment: Thank you! The last code listing was really helpful. I shows me that i misinterpreted the "+=" operator in the first place.

(x[y] += 1 --[ is equivalent to ]--> x[y] = x[y] + 1), (x[y] += 1 --[ is not equivalent to ]--> x = x[y] + 1)